# Universal initialization - vector's fill constructor

Tags: c++, initialization, c++17, stdvector

Is it possible in c++17 to call this constructor

```
 vector( size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

using uniform initialization for `vector<int>`? It seems that `std::vector<int> data{10, 20}` creates a vector of size two.

Comment: The short answer is no. This question has been asked here before though tracking it down might not be easy.

Comment: Can we take a moment to appreciate "uniform" initialization?

Comment: Does it mean that we need to mix: use uniform and old-way initialization?

Comment: @RSahu The short answer is yes, the longer answer is don't. :-)

Comment: @Barry, good call.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: I love it. Now I can, regardless of type, use `{}` to construct an object from a list of data, and `()` for a non-data constructor. Nice and consistent.  I merely find the fact that `{}` _can_ call other constructors to be a flaw in C++.

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible? Sure.

```
struct size_type {
    template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, std::vector<int>::size_type>>* = nullptr>
    operator T() const {
        return val;
    }
    std::vector<int>::size_type val;
};

std::vector<int> vi {size_type{10}, 4}; // vector of 10 ints with value 4
```

This works as long as `value_type` is not the same type as `size_type`.

Should you do it? No.

Comment: what will `std::vector<std::size_t> vi {size_type{10}, 4};` do? (assuming that `std::vector<std::size_t>::size_type` is `std::size_t`)

Comment: it looks like it calls the initializer list ctor (`std::vector<std::size_t>` version) https://godbolt.org/z/2RKg4C

Comment: @bolov Yes, hence the caveat. Note that the question only asked about `vector<int>`.

Comment: I was just curious

Answer (score 4):

Sure:

```
std::vector<int> vi{10, 4, std::allocator<int>()};
```

But there's nothing inherently wrong with parentheses.

Comment: It seems that using uniform initialization lets you avoid some errors. Thus I hoped to use it all over the place instead of parentheses. BTW good workaround:)